# Linux ubuntu Awk. Find the sentences containg 2 same words placed near themselves

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to print all the sentences that contains two same words next to each other.
The sentence is ending with . or ? or !.

For the input:

```
word ja ba word. Na Na word wdd? Nothing kkk
ok ok! word no this no word. ok ok. notok!
```

output should be:

```
Na Na word wdd?

Nothing kkk
ok ok!

ok ok.
```

This is my code so far:

```
 #!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
 then
echo "No arguments"
 fi

if [[ -f $1 ]] #if its file
then

cat $1 | awk '{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)         
  {

}}'

fi
```

I dont know how to separate full sentences with AWK. I can't use multpile file separators (! its important). If I separate them, how to check every word inside? I need to use AWK.

this is my newest idea:

```
cat $1 | awk  '{
 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)         
  {
   a=0;
    if ($i ~ "\?$" || $i ~ "\!$" || $i ~ "\.$")          
    {

  #print $i;
      k='';

    for(j=$i; j!=$a; j--);
    {
      if( $j == $k)
        #print whole sentence

       $k=$j;

    }

    }
}}'
```

I found the words ending with ?/./!, then check all the previous words before the last sentence

Comment: Why did `Nothing kkk` come in the output? It shouldnt

Comment: theres newline(\n) in the middle, and the sentence is ending only with ./?/!

Comment: When you say you have to use AWK, do you mean you don't have (or can't use) `gawk`?  Because with gawk you can use a regex as the record separator `gawk  -v RS='[!?.]' ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` is enough to do so :

```
grep -Pzo "[^.?!]*\b(\w+) \1[^.?!]*"
```

Test:

```
$ echo '''word ja ba word. Na Na word wdd? Nothing kkk  
ok ok! word no this no word. ok ok. notok!''' | grep -Pzo "[^.?!]*\b(\w+) \1[^.?!]*"  
Na Na word wdd  
Nothing kkk  
ok ok  
ok ok
```

Explanation :

- the `-o` flag makes `grep` only return the matched result, rather than the line it appears in
- the `-P` flag makes `grep` use PCRE regex
- the `-z` flag suppress newline at the end of line, substituting it for nul character. That is, grep knows where end of line is, but sees the input as one big line.
- `[^.?!]*` matches the start of the sentence : it will match as much characters as it can, but no sentence terminators (.?!)
- `\b(\w+)` matches word characters, and groups them in the first group of the regular expression. The word boundary makes sure we do not only match the end of a word (thanks 123 !).
- `\1` references this first group, so we must have two identical words separated by a space
- `[^.?!]*` matches the end of the sentence

Comment: `cat $1 | grep -Pzo "[^.?!]*(\w+) \1[^.?!]*"`  doesnt work for me ( I am using Ubuntu)

Comment: Nevermind. I selected the wrong text file as arg. Works great. Can you do it with awk? Good job anyway and thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `awk`, I usually solve all my tasks with `grep` or `sed`. You're obviously free to wait for an `awk` answer to accept, I'll leave this one here in case someone with the same problem does not have your tool constraint :)

Comment: btw as a side note, `grep <pattern> <file>` is a cleaner (and possibly more efficient) alternative to `cat <file> | grep <pattern>` :)

Comment: This will match sentences such as `wow ow` you need a delimiter before the first match. `"[^.?!]*\b(\w+) \1[^.?!]*"`

Answer (score 2):

with `gawk`

```
$ awk -v RS='[!?.] +' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i==$(i+1)) print $0 RT "\n"}' file

Na Na word wdd?

Nothing kkk
ok ok!

ok ok.
```

set the records ending with `[!?.]` and optional space.  Iterate over words in the sentence for repeats, print the sentence with matched record terminator and new line for spacing between sentences.

Here is the same script with the here document

```
awk -v RS='[!?.] +' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if($i==$(i+1)) print $0 RT "\n"}' << EOF
> word ja ba word. Na Na word wdd? Nothing kkk
> ok ok! word no this no word. ok ok. notok!
> EOF
```

should give you

```
Na Na word wdd?

Nothing kkk
ok ok!

ok ok.
```

Comment: it doesnt print `Nothing kkk ok ok` for me

Comment: what is your `awk --version`?